# How to center this horizontal list of images?

Tags: css, html-lists, centering

In the following fiddle you see 3 images.
I want to center the UL on the screen. It seems to be impossible for me. Can anybody help?

https://jsfiddle.net/dtnp5ko2/

```css
.loc-caption:before {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="float: left;width: 25%;list-style-type:none;" class="loc-caption" title="location 1">
    <img id="loc1" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-showroom.jpg" width="100%"/>
  </li>
  <li style="float: left;width: 25%;list-style-type:none;" class="loc-caption" title="location 2">
    <img id="loc2" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-kantoor.jpg" width="100%"/>
  <li style="float: left;width: 25%;list-style-type:none;" class="loc-caption" title="location 3">
    <img id="loc3" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-magazijn.jpg" width="100%"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE: Thank you Pangloss. Your codes center the UL on the screen.
The images are not automatically placed on the same horizontal level.
If I type some more text above 1 image, then that images shifts down.
How to align the 3 images on the same horizontal level, exactly next to each other?

```
    <ul>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 1: office and warehouse ">
    <img id="loc1" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-showroom.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 2">
    <img id="loc2" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-kantoor.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 3">
    <img id="loc3" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-magazijn.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see the problem here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtnp5ko2/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`, so it's easy to center the elements.

Remove `width="100%"` from `<img>` tags, although it works in this case, because percentage width is relative to the container's width, and you have it defined on the `<li>`, but use CSS `max-width:100%` is a better choice to me, very maintainable.

And you have an unclosed `<li>`, so fix that too.

```css
.loc-caption:before {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 1">
    <img id="loc1" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-showroom.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 2">
    <img id="loc2" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-kantoor.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="loc-caption" title="location 3">
    <img id="loc3" src="http://design-boxsprings.nl/beeld-matrl/locatie-magazijn.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** change `vertical-align` value from `top` to `bottom` to align the images to the bottom.